# Is it bad to use Disqus on a public repository where people can see the script?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, disqus

I am using Jekyll plus Github Pages with the free plan, so people can see the code for my blog easily, and i've been wondering, is the script for Disqus to insert it on the website not mean to be public?

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = "{{page.id}}";
this.page.identifier = "{{page.url}}";
};
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://website.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visitors of your site will be able to see it if they look at the webpage source.

There are no risks in having them in public repos.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, how could i miss that one haha